# horizontal scroll issue in mobile using javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, horizontal-scrolling

i have a website which is horizontal scrolling which works perfectly in desktop, for the pages i have used javascript like below:

```js
var item = {};
item.name = "#home-page";
item.stackOrder = 99;
item.content = "html";
item.screenPos = ["center", "-150%", "-250%", "-350%", "-450%", "-550%", "-650%"];
item.offsetV = 150;
item.visibility = ["true", "true", "true", "true", "true", "true", "true"];
items.push(item);
var item = {};
item.name = "#aboutus-page";
item.stackOrder = 99;
item.content = "html";
item.screenPos = ["150%", "center", "-150%", "-250%", "-350%", "-450%", "-550%"];
item.offsetV = 0;
item.visibility = ["true", "true", "true", "true", "true", "true", "true"];

items.push(item);
var item = {};
item.name = "#blog-page";
item.stackOrder = 99;
item.content = "html";
item.screenPos = ["250%", "150%", "center", "-150%", "-250%", "-350%", "-450%"];
item.offsetV = 0;
item.visibility = ["true", "true", "true", "true", "true", "true", "true"];
items.push(item);
var item = {};
item.name = "#portfolio-page";
item.stackOrder = 99;
item.content = "html";
item.screenPos = ["350%", "250%", "150%", "center", "-150%", "-250%", "-350%"];
item.offsetV = 0;
item.visibility = ["true", "true", "true", "true", "true", "true", "true"];
items.push(item);

var item = {};
item.name = "#shark-page";
item.stackOrder = 99;
item.content = "html";
item.screenPos = ["450%", "350%", "250%", "150%", "center", "-150%", "-250%"];
item.offsetV = 0;
item.visibility = ["true", "true", "true", "true", "true", "true", "true"];
items.push(item);


var item = {};
item.name = "#gallery-page";
item.stackOrder = 99;
item.content = "html";
item.screenPos = ["450%", "350%", "250%", "150%", "250%", "center", "-250%"];
item.offsetV = 0;
item.visibility = ["true", "true", "true", "true", "true", "true", "true"];
items.push(item);

var item = {};
item.name = "#journey-page";
item.stackOrder = 99;
item.content = "html";
item.screenPos = ["450%", "350%", "250%", "150%", "250%", "350%", "center"];
item.offsetV = 0;
item.visibility = ["true", "true", "true", "true", "true", "true", "true"];
items.push(item);
```

the issue is whatever i do, its not coming properly in mobile, the live url is like:
[live url](https://demo.thebrandchimp.com/cocofit)
can anyone please tell me is there a way to make this fit in mobile devices